# How to wirte JPQL SELECT MAX with embedded id?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink, jpql, composite-key

I'm using Eclipselink (JPA) + GlassFish v3.1.2 + NetBeans 7.1.2

I have one table with composite primary key:

```
table (Enterpirse)
----------------------
|PK,FK idCompany     | nvarchar
|PK idEnterprisecode | nvarchar
|                    |
|____________________|

@Entity
public class IdMtoEnterprise {
    @EmbeddedId
    protected IdMtoEnterprisePK idMtoEnterprisePK

    //getter and setter are omitted for clear
}

@Embeddable
public class IdMtoEnterprisePK {

    @Column(name = "id_mto_company")
    private String idMtoCompany;

    @Column(name = "id_mto_enterprise_code")
    private String idMtoEnterpriseCode;
}
```

Now.. how do I write SELECT MAX(with EmbeddedId)  clause with JPQL ???

this fail...

```
Select MAX(e.IdMtoEnterprisePK.idMtoEnterpriseCode) From IdMtoEnterprise e
```

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Error compiling the query [Select MAX(e.IdMtoEnterprisePK.idMtoEnterpriseCode) From IdMtoEnterprise e], line 1, column 13: unknown state or association field [IdMtoEnterprisePK] of class [com.sdn.entidad.IdMtoEnterprise].

Answer (score 1):

Your field is named `idMtoEnterprisePK` (lower-case i), and not `IdMtoEnterprisePK` (upper-case I).